# Margin not clickable in <a> tag (Foundation 4)

Tags: css, html, margin, zurb-foundation

I am creating a server file table using the Foundation 4 framework and seem to be having an issue where not all of the row is clickable when the filename goes on to two lines. I need the whole shaded row to be a link.

[See the image of the clickable area I highlighted in Photoshop.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqdtg.jpg)

The HTML structure of each row is as follows:

```
<div class="fileTable row alternate">
    <a class="icon folder" href="#">
        <div class="large-10 columns margin">test folder test folder test folder test folder test folder test folder test folder test folder test folder test folder test folder test folder test folder</div>
        <div class="large-2 hide-for-small columns margin">23/05/2013</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

The class of .margin seems the be the issue. It was added to centralise the text vertically within each row, it adds 7px top and bottom. I would have used line-height and set it to the same height of each row (44px) but that was causing a huge gap in between the lines of any filename that went onto two lines.

The screenshot above is exactly how I need it to look, it just for some reason won't behave correctly as a link.

The CSS for the fileTable links is as follows:

```
.fileTable a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

.margin {
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}
```

The rest of the classes you see are either for displaying the icons, alternating the shading or standard Foundation 4 grid classes.

Answer (score 5):

Please read about the **[CSS Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)**. Margin isn't considered to be part of "the box", hence it isn't clickable.

You should be using `padding` instead, then it would be.